# Disable 'no-duplicate-dollar-variables' for variables declared as !default

Tags: sass, stylelint

A code snippet dealing with the scenario:

```css
$unfolded-transitions: () !default;
@each $transition in $transitions {
    $unfolded-transitions: append($unfolded-transitions, unfoldTransition($transition), comma); /* stylelint-disable-line scss/no-duplicate-dollar-variables */
}
```

Here I have explicitly used `stylelint-disable-line` comment to skip the rule. Is it possible to tell stylelint to skip the 'no-duplicate-dollar-variables' rule when a variable is initialized with default as in the case above. In case if a value is assigned to a variable, then stylelint should report the required warning if there are duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to tell stylelint to skip the 'no-duplicate-dollar-variables' rule when a variable is initialized with default as in the case above

It is not possible but it should be.

I recommend you [create a new issue in the stylelint-scss tracker](https://github.com/kristerkari/stylelint-scss/issues/new) and suggest that the `no-duplicate-dollar-variables` rule takes into account `!default` variables.